# Ion-Slides resize() doesn’t work

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a simple ion-slides element, which works quite good so far.
My only problem is, when i change the device orientation, because it doesn’t resize the slide element’s wide.

html:

```
<ion-slides #slides>

 <ion-slide>
   <h2>Slide 1</h2>
 </ion-slide>

 <ion-slide>
   <h2>Slide 2</h2>
 </ion-slide>

 <ion-slide>
   <h2>Slide 3</h2>
 </ion-slide>
```

.ts-file:

```
export class DetailviewPage {
  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;
.
.
.
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.screenOrientation.onChange().subscribe(() => {
      this.slides.resize();
    });
.
.
.
```

css-file:

```
 ion-slides {
        height: auto;
    }
    ion-slide {
        height: initial !important;
        align-items: flex-start !important;
    }
```

other functions like slideNext() work perfectly.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: What's the attached css to ion-slide? Has this a width and height of 100%?

Comment: ion-slides {
        height: auto;
    }
    ion-slide {
        height: initial !important;
        align-items: flex-start !important;
    }

Comment: Any solutions??

Comment: In my case `slides.update()` did the trick when the screen size changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.screenOrientation.onChange().subscribe(() => {
    this.slides.resize();
    this.slides.update();
  });
}
```